# Reality Composer file appears missing on html page

Tags: augmented-reality, reality-composer

I created a .reality file from reality composer with image recognition anchor. I uploaded both the image and .reality file to my github repo along with the html page all in the same root folder. In the html file I have the following

```
<html>
  <a rel=”ar” href=”NameOfFile.reality”> <img src=”NameOfImage.jpg” alt=””></a>
</html>
```

When I scan the QR code to the home repo the html loads but the .reality file doesnt seem to activate.